# set default value to jquery range slider

Tags: php, jquery, range

I am trying to set default value to jquery range slider but it is not working for me. I have values in php array and using them in the range slider I want to select default value I have code below:

```
$sum = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `sum_insured` FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}dh_insurance_plans_rates` WHERE `plan_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM wp_dh_insurance_plans WHERE `product`='$product_id') GROUP BY `sum_insured` ORDER BY CAST(`sum_insured` AS DECIMAL)");
?> 
var SliderValues = [<?php
                $s = 0;
                foreach($sum as $suma){
                $s++;   
                echo $sumamount = $suma->sum_insured;
                if($s < $wpdb->num_rows){
                echo ', ';
                }
                } ?>];
$(function () {
    $("#sum_slider").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: SliderValues.length - 1,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('#coverage_amount').text(SliderValues[ui.value]);
            $( "#coverage_amount" ).val( "$" + SliderValues[ui.value] );
        }
    });
    $( "#coverage_amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#sum_slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Comment: Have you checked what is the value coming in SliderValues variable ?

Comment: I tired to set value in slider like this value: 100000, but after this slider position is setting to very last and value coming is $8 instead of 100000

Comment: Can you please share value coming in $sum ?

Comment: These values are coming: 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 150000, 200000, 300000

Answer (score 0):

I think try to change max value of slider. Instead of 
"max: SliderValues.length - 1" ... Use like:

```
max: SliderValues[SliderValues.length - 1]
```

Comment: After adding this code how can I set default value ?

Comment: I tried to add value: 100000, and this time it is setting default value 100000 which is good but when I try to move slider it is saying: $undefined can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just done it by myself the way like:

```
var selct_value = SliderValues.indexOf;
```

AND Used

```
value: selct_value,
```